# Is it possible to translate an image into raw text and then reverse it?

Tags: php, image, encoding, lua, translation

I have a picture. For whatever reason, I need that picture to be sent to an environment that can only receive text and not images. Images and other files must be sent through their filter and I want to get around this. I calculated that there would be 480,000 independent hex values being manipulated but this is really the only option I have. Also, is it possible to compress and uncompress it for less pixels being sent? I will need to send the picture from a PHP web server [lets say, mysite.com/image.php] and receive it in Lua, and my only connection to the server is over a web request. No ftp, no even loading image files. Just setting 480,000 variables to the different id's

Oh, one more thing: it needs to not crash my server when I run it. ;)

Comment: See mime encoding / base64

Comment: You will need a third party plugin to compress your image after that you can convert it to base64 (this is a pretty long string)

Answer (score 1):

Convert your image to base64 (Eg: Can pass to the variable).

Eg: I converted PNG image
Base 64 image will look like this.

> `"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAYAAADEUlfTAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAE9JREFUeNpiYMADGLEJKssrCACp+Uw4JPYD8QdGHBIP7j58EMgCFDAAcvqBOBGI64FYAMpmYIFqAilYD6Udgbo+IBvXAMT/gXg9sjUAAQYAG6IS47QjgzEAAAAASUVORK5CYII="`

You can use it in image source to display.

Hope this helps!